# Httplib2 ssl error

Tags: python, foursquare, httplib2

Today I faced one interesting issue.

I'm using the foursquare recommended python library httplib2 raise

```
SSLHandshakeError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'),)
```

while trying to request an oauth token

```
response, body = h.request(url, method, headers=headers, body=data)
```

in

```
_process_request_with_httplib2 function
```

does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SSL certificate verification failed **:-D**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you know that the site you're trying to get is a "good guy", you can try creating your "opener" like this:

```
import httplib2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    h = httplib2.Http(".cache", disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
    resp, content = h.request("https://site/whose/certificate/is/bad/", "GET")
```

(the interesting part is `disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True` )

From the docs:
http://bitworking.org/projects/httplib2/doc/html/libhttplib2.html#httplib2.Http

**EDIT 01:**

Since your question was actually why does this happen, you can check [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-errors.html) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificates).

**EDIT 02:**

Seeing how this answer has been visited by more people than I expected, I'd like to explain a bit *when* disabling certificate validation could be useful.

First, a bit of light background on how these certificates work. There's quite a lot of information in the links provided above, but here it goes, anyway.

The SSL certificates need to be verified by a well known (at least, well known to your browser) [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). You usually buy the whole certificate from one of those authorities ([Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/ssl-certificates/), [GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/web-security/ssl-certificate)...)

Broadly speaking, the idea is: Those Certificate Authorities (CA) give you a certificate that also contains *the CA information* in it. Your browsers have a list of well known CAs, so when your browser receives a certificate, it will do something like: *"HmmmMMMmmm....* <sub>[the browser makes a supiciuous face here]</sub> *... I received a certificate, and it says it's verified by Symantec. Do I know that "Symantec" guy?* <sub>[the browser then goes to its list of well known CAs and checks for Symantec]</sub> *Oh, yeah! I do. Ok, the certificate is good!*

You can see that information yourself if you click on the little lock by the URL in your browser:

[image: Chrome certificate information]

However, there are cases in which you just want to test the HTTPS, and you create your own Certificate Authority using a couple of [command line](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html) tools and you use that "custom" CA to sign a "custom" certificate that you just generated as well, right? In that case, your browser (which, by the way, in the question is `httplib2.Http`) is not going to have your "custom" CA among the list of trusted CAs, so it's going to say that the certificate is invalid. The information is still going to travel encrypted, but what the browser is telling you is that it doesn't fully trust that is traveling encrypted to the place you are supposing it's going.

For instance, let's say you created a set of custom keys and CAs and all the mambo-jumbo following [this tutorial](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/) for your `localhost` [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) and that your CA certificate file is located in the current directory. You could very well have a server running on `https://localhost:4443` using your custom certificates and whatnot. Now, your CA certificate file is located in the current directory, in the file `./ca.crt` (in the same directory your Python script is going to be running in). You could use `httplib2` like this:

```
h = httplib2.Http(ca_certs='./ca.crt')
response, body = h.request('https://localhost:4443')
print(response)
print(body)
```

... and you wouldn't see the warning anymore. Why? Because you told `httplib2` to go look for the CA's certificate to `./ca.crt`)

However, since Chrome (to cite a browser) doesn't know about this CA's certificate, it will consider it invalid:

[image]

Also, certificates expire. There's a chance you are working in a company which uses an internal site with SSL encryption. It works ok for a year, and then your browser starts complaining. You go to the person that is in charge of the security, and ask *"Yo!! I get this warning here! What's happening?"* And the answer could very well be *"Oh boy!! I forgot to renew the certificate! It's ok, just accept it from now, until I fix that."* (true story, although there were swearwords in the answer I received **:-D** )

Comment: This is really not a great idea - you should really figure out why your validation is failing. By disabling the validation, you are in essence removing the ability to detect many man-in-the-middle-attacks, where someone wants to impersonate the upstream Foursquare server - you won't be able to detect even the simple case where they have generated a self-signed cert.

Comment: Remark: for disabling certificate validation it's just `h = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)` needed.

Comment: @javanix, hence the *If you know that the site you're trying to get is a "good guy"...*

Comment: *facepalm* at the number of upvotes this solution has received and the number of views this page has received. This suggestion shows a lack of understanding of the purpose of certificate validation and should be deleted from this list of answers. It's not about trusting the actual site, it's about trusting everything inbetween. As @javanix mentioned, it's to protect the client from man in the middle attacks.

Comment: @deltaray, as the original poster of this answer, I would invite you to read the Edit 02 that I made and explain how you'd overcome the issues with a self-signed certificate or a website that forgot to renew their certs, specially if you need quick access to it. Because that happens in real life. A lot.

Answer (score 13):

Recent versions of httplib2 is defaulting to its own certificate store.

```
# Default CA certificates file bundled with httplib2.
CA_CERTS = os.path.join(
     os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )), "cacerts.txt")
```

In case if you're using ubuntu/debian, you can explicitly pass the path to system certificate file like

```
httplib2.HTTPSConnectionWithTimeout(HOST, ca_certs="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could be the case:
I got the same problem and debugging the Google Lib I found out that the reason was that I was using an older version of `httplib2`(0.9.2). When I updated to the most recent (0.14.0) it worked.

If you already install the most recent, make sure that some lib is not installing an older version of `httplib2` inside its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

When you see this error with a self-signed certificate, as often happens inside a corporate proxy, you can point httplib2 to your custom certificate bundle using an environment variable. When, for example, you don't want to (or can't) modify the code to pass the `ca_certs` parameter.
You can also do this when you don't want to modify the system certificate store to append your CA cert.

```
export HTTPLIB2_CA_CERTS="\path\to\your\CA_certs_bundle"
```