# Google Cloud SDK installation fails on Windows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk

Tried installing Google SDK on Windows 2016 machine using both online and offline install. In both the cases installation fails with below error. Machine is behind firewall.
ERROR: (gcloud.components.update) Failed to fetch component listing from server. Check your network settings and try again.

Comment: The CLI `gcloud` cannot connect to a Google server. 1) There are not enough details in your question to create an answer. 2) Did the installation complete or fail? 3) What type of connection to the Internet do you have? Are you using a proxy server? 4) If the CLI installed review the output from `gcloud --verbosity=DEBUG auth login` to understand what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

When the error `ERROR: (gcloud.components.list)` appears, it means that GCloud is attempting to make a request to the following url: https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json.

It seems that your configuration prevents this URL from being fetched, and there could be many factors for this behavior.

My suggestion is to:

1. Check if dl.google.com is part of the allowed IPs in your firewall rules.
   According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings) if you are behind a proxy/firewall, the components that the Cloud SDK installers download from the internet may not work correctly.
2. Sometimes this error is caused because SSL Cert Verification is failing for the component listing request from Google's servers. I have found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30448701/14004844) where someone from the community resolved this issue.
   Also, I found this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30441026/) with a similar problem.
3. For a simpler installation process when proxy configuration is necessary, you might follow [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives) to install the SDK using self-contained versioned archives.
4. I have found another [post](https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/python/instalacion-del-sdk-de-google-cloud-en-os-x-gcloud.components.list-error-al-recuperar-la-lista-de-componentes-del-servidor/832334366/) where a user with the same error message was able to resolve it only disabling the IPv6, you can  use the follow the [next guide](https://tweaks.com/windows/40099/how-to-properly-disable-ipv6/#:%7E:text=The%20proper%20way%20to%20disable,(32%2Dbit)%20Value.) to disable your IPv6 on windows

Comment: I'm happy to know the answer was useful, in order to help the community in the future, could you please accept or upvote the answer? Thanks